# Syntax prevents computed fields to populate using @DbLookup

Tags: javascript, xpages, xsp

I have a combo Box that lists several products.  Some of these products have quotes in their names signifying inches (i.e. 12" dressing Rod).  Here is my issue.  I have an "On Change" event that updates several computed fields using @DbLookup populating Product Cost, Unit of Measure, & Item Number.  When I select any product that uses a quote to signify inches, the computed fields do not populate.  What is the significance of the quote in the product name & how do I fix this?  Here is the code from the Combo Box.

```
try {
        var vendor = getComponent("POVendor").getValue();
        var list = @DbLookup(@DbName(), "VPL", vendor, 2);
        if (@IsError(list))
            return "Select a Vendor first|";
        else
            return list;
    } catch (e) {
        return "Please select a vendor first (Error)|";
    }
```

Here is the code from the computed field (it's actually an edit box that is read only & the code is the default value.) that populates with the Item Cost:

```
var item = getComponent("Item1").getValue();

var cost = @DbLookup(@DbName(), "PL", item, 2);

return cost;
```

Comment: It would help if you would post the relevant code here but my first guess would be that you are going to have to escape the "

Comment: I agree: something "happens" with the value, that makes Notes think, you want to "evaluate" the content. This for sure is not a normal behaviour and must be in your code. Please give us the code that causes the issue, then We can help you...

Comment: Sorry about that.  I thought the code would be irrelevant.  Here it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the product list was imported I needed a way to change the " to "in.". I did by using an agent & changed all of the product names containing """ & replaced them with "in.". That worked. Now I'm just going to write a script that prohibits use of the " mark for Inches.

Comment: I tested the system & replaced the double quote mark with two single quote marks & it worked perfectly.  What is the significance of the double as oposed to single quotes?

Comment: Now I have another conundrum.  The only fields that bind to a form field on my form are the xpage fields where I enter the data manually.  Any computed value doesn't save in the appropriate form fields.  What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using inch symbol?. If so you can try replacing it with the equivalent hex code \u2033.

```
var item = getComponent("Item1").getValue();
var cost = @DbLookup(@DbName(), "PL", @ReplaceSubstring(item, '″', '\u2033'), 2);
return cost;
```

If you're using right double quotation mark, your hex code will be \u201D.

Please look at this link, http://www.javascripter.net/faq/mathsymbols.htm to find the different types of codes for a given character.

Please give a try and let us know.

Comment: Since the product list was imported I needed a way to change the " to "in.".  I did by using an agent & changed all of the product names containing """ & replaced them with "in.".  That worked.  Now I'm just going to write a script that prohibits use of the " mark for Inches.  Thanks for the helpl